# Signature of the function with default parameters

Tags: scala, default-parameters

> def addition(a:Int, b:Int = 5) = a + b
>
> val k = addition _
>
> k(2) //This does not work

Also If I want to pass k as a parameter to another function what should be the signature of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Function objects don't have default values. The type of `k` is `(Int, Int) => Int`.

Comment: correct. how can I get this working?

Comment: `val k = (a: Int) => addition(a)`